# WPF Drag, drop image into canvas, reject wrong ones

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have 8 images and 2 canvas, and i am trying to do a drag drop game, which will be able to reject the wrong image that is drop into the wrong canvas. I tried many codes online just for the drag drop function but it didn't work. The most common error I have is

1) "The type 'WpfApplication9.Window1' already contains a definition for 'butterfly'"

2) 'WpfApplication9.Window1' does not contain a definition for 'Grid_PreviewMouseDown' and no extension method 'Grid_PreviewMouseDown' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication9.Window1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do solve the problem? Thankyou in advance

Comment: could you post some code, or perhaps a working sample which can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

These are *very* basic errors and developers typically solve these by pasting them into any search engine and reading the result pages. If you can't fix these kinds of problems yourself, you'll have *real* problems later. Either way, your first error is this:

> The type 'WpfApplication9.Window1' already contains a definition for 'butterfly'

In plain English, this means that you have a class named `Window1` in a namespace named `'WpfApplication9` (so I'm assuming this is your 9th test application) and in that class, you have declared a property, method, `enum`, or other member named `butterfly`... the *actual* problem is that you have defined two members named `butterfly` in the same class. You cannot do this, so rename one of them.

Your second error is:

> 'WpfApplication9.Window1' does not contain a definition for 'Grid_PreviewMouseDown' and no extension method 'Grid_PreviewMouseDown' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication9.Window1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Again, this is a very common error and simply means that you have attached a `PreviewMouseDown` event handler to your `Grid`, but then you didn't actually declare the handler method itself. The solution is to implement your `Grid_PreviewMouseDown` method.